# Чем открыть файл owl?

Tags: owl-carousel

Мне отправили файл с кодом расширения .owl
У отправителя нет возможности спросить, ничего лучше не придумал, чем спросить здесь...
Так вот, какой программой открыть и запустить код в файле с расширением owl?

Comment: [Этой](https://protege.stanford.edu) наверное.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [fileInfo](https://www.file-info.ru/).

Или можно попробовать обычный текстовый редактор.